# Pasar un valor de un putExtra

Tags: android, api, kotlin, android-corrutinas

tengo una pregunta.
Estoy obteniendo una lista de una API, en un Recyclerview y tiene un botón por cada item de la lista. Cuando selecciono uno, debe abrir otra lista de la misma API que corresponde a la que seleccione. Tengo que pasar el ID del elemento seleccionado para que lo asigne como parámetro al @GET. Para pasarlo a otra pantalla utilizo el intent.putExtra().
Y ya en una Corrutina llama al método que contiene el @GET y le paso el valor del putExtra() para recuperar la lista que corresponde de la API. Pero cuando llego al runOnUiThread y tiene que pasar la lista me returna un erro de java.lang.NullPointerException.
Y seguidame dice:
at com... $onCreate$1.invokeSuspend$lambda$0

```
class CapadeDatos {
data class PRUEBACORTA(
            @SerializedName("IDENTIFICADOR1") var IDENTIFICADOR1: Number,
            @SerializedName("FECHACREACION1") var FECHACREACION1: String,
            @SerializedName("FECHAAPLICACION1") var FECHAAPLICACION1: String,
            @SerializedName("HORAINICIO1") var  HORAINICIO1: String,
            @SerializedName("DURACION1") var DURACION1: String,
            @SerializedName("CENTROEDUCATIVO1") var CENTROEDUCATIVO1: String,
            @SerializedName("ASIGNATURA1") var ASIGNATURA1: String,
            @SerializedName("PERIODO1") var PERIODO1: String,
            @SerializedName("NIVEL1") var NIVEL1: String,
            @SerializedName("PUNTOSTOTALES1") var PUNTOSTOTALES1: String,
            @SerializedName("PORCENTAJETOTAL1") var PORCENTAJETOTAL1: String,
            @SerializedName("Itemnesdetiposeleccion") var itemnesdetiposeleccion:MutableList<PRUEBACORTA_ITEMRESPPUESTAUNICA>

        )

        data class PRUEBACORTA_ITEMRESPPUESTAUNICA(
            @SerializedName("IDITEM1") var IDITEM1:ITEMTIPOSELECCIONUNICADELESTUDIANTE,
            @SerializedName("IDENTIFICADORPRUEBACORTA1") var IDENTIFICADORPRUEBACORTA1: PRUEBACORTA,
            @SerializedName("ORDEN1") var ORDEN1:Number,
            @SerializedName("CONTEXTO1") var CONTEXTO1:String
        )
}

 fun bind(prueba: CapadeDatos.PRUEBACORTA, context: Context) {
            Asinatura.text = prueba.ASIGNATURA1
            Fecha.text = prueba.FECHAAPLICACION1 + " Duracion: " + prueba.DURACION1.toString()
            Detalle.text =
                prueba.CENTROEDUCATIVO1 + " Nivel: " + prueba.NIVEL1 + " Periodo: " + prueba.PERIODO1

            botonir.setOnClickListener {
                SharedApp.eventoseleccionado = prueba
                val id = prueba.IDENTIFICADOR1.toInt()
                val intent = Intent(context, PruebaCortaRespuestaUnica::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("IdPruebaCorta", id.toString())
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
class PruebaCortaRespuestaUnica : AppCompatActivity() {

val bundle = intent. Extras
val name = bundle?.get("idPruebaCorta").toString()
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val callRespuestaUnica = retrofit.create(ApiServices::class.java)
                .obtenerPruebaCorta_ItemRespuestaUnica(name).execute()

            runOnUiThread {
                SharedApp.pruebasCortas = callRespuestaUnica.body()!!
                Log.i("Lista cruda del servidor", callRespuestaUnica.body().toString())
                setUpRecyclerViewRespuestaUnica()
            }
        }
fun setUpRecyclerViewRespuestaUnica(){
        rRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_pruebaCorta_RespuestaUnica)
        rRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        rRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rAdapter.AdaptadorPruebaCorta_ItemRespuestaUnica(SharedApp.pruebasCortas, this)
        rRecyclerView.adapter = rAdapter

    }

class SharedApp: Application(){

    companion object {
        lateinit var pruebasCortas: MutableList<CapadeDatos.PRUEBACORTA_ITEMRESPPUESTAUNICA>
        lateinit var pruebasdelmes: MutableList<CapadeDatos.PRUEBACORTA>
        lateinit var eventoseleccionado: CapadeDatos.PRUEBACORTA
        lateinit var eventoSeleccionadoRespuestaUnica: CapadeDatos.PRUEBACORTA_ITEMRESPPUESTAUNICA
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
//guardamos una lista de la clase fecha, que nos debe devolver la peticion
        pruebasdelmes = ArrayList()
        pruebasCortas = ArrayList()

    }

}
```

Comment: Para poderte ayudar de una manera más optima, deberías de colocar tu código, ya que así no hay modo de saber cómo ayudarte

Comment: Gracias, ahi agregue parte del codigo.